# How to delete unnecessary custom post types in the UI

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, posts, customization

I am using Wordpress 4.8 and have a custom post type that I can't find a way to delete.

It was created by someone else and i'm not sure where, however I can tell it wasn't created with the [CPT UI](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) which is where I created the custom post type.

I have deleted all the posts that belong to this post type (and cleared the trash), but it still shows in the menu.

How can I delete this in the UI without writing PHP or updating the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way on the backend (UI) for unregistering a post type, the 
process however is quite simple.

Andrew Nacin provided some code over on https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14761

You can easily create a plugin with this function and have the CPT unregister.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'unregister_post_type' ) ) :
function unregister_post_type( $post_type ) {
global $wp_post_types;
if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] ) ) {
    unset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] );
    return true;
}
return false;
}
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I feared it would have to be done in code. Outside of the CPT UI, how can a custom post type be created?

Comment: Most probably is coming from your theme - if you are interested to find out just get your theme downloaded to your local computer and search inside your folder's theme for the CPT slug name.

Comment: What do you mean by "coming from your theme"? As in - it is actually hard-coded in the theme's `functions.php`?

Comment: Yes hard coded to in theme

Comment: You can search without downloading it locally, using the plugin "String Locator"